# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How to insert and query utf8 string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert Arabic word into Database using Flask-SQLAlchemy but I'm getting alloot of errors.

What I'm doing is :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sqlite3.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, username, email):
        self.username = username
        self.email = email

db.create_all()
test = Basic_Settings("مرحباً", "admin@gmail.com")
db.session.add(test)
db.session.commit()
```

Soo I'm getting this error :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (sqlite3.ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings. [SQL: u'INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('\xd9\x85\xd8\xb1\xd8\xad\xd8\xa8\xd8\xa7\xd9\x8b', 'admin@gmail.com')]
```

Then I r-edit my code and set utf-8 to this Arabic word like this :

```
test = User("مرحباً".decode("utf-8"), "admin@gmail.com")
```

so now terminal not showing any errors

After that I need to query this data and write it into file or I want to define this data so I add this to my code :

```
all = User.query.all()
f = open("utf-8.txt", "w")
f.write([x.username for x in all])
f.close()
```

And now I'm getting this error :

```
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object
```

Is there any way to fix this problem here I don't want just to write this to file I want also to define it like :

```
username2 = [x.username for x in all]
```

without any error.

Comment: You're trying to write a `list` when you need a `str`.

Comment: @univerio ok, so when I edit it to : f.write(str([x.username for x in all]))

It's write to file something like this : [u'\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627\u064b']

What should I do here ?

Comment: Well, what do you want to do? What are you expecting to write to the file?

Comment: @univerio I want to define this not write it like : username2 = str([x.username for x in all])

then I want to use it in homepage like :

return render_template("main.html", username = username2)

it's work but it's returned something like this : [u'\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627\u064b']

And I don't know how to fix it. thank u.

Comment: You can't blindly convert a `list` to a `str`. If you don't tell Python **exactly** how you want the `str` to look, it's going to print the default string representation of a list. So, again, what **exactly** do you want the string to look like?

Comment: @univerio I insert this string "مرحباً" and I want to look like this also : مرحباً
also If I input this string "Hello" I want to look like this "Hello"

Comment: But you have a list of multiple strings, not a single string, that means you can have `["Foo", "Bar"]`, in which case what do you want to show?

Comment: Then just get the first element of the list... `all[0].username`

Comment: @univerio I think u didn't understand me :(

I can get query of this table but I'm inserting Arabic & English Words
So my I insert this to table :

User("مرحباً", "admin@gmail.com")
User("Hello", "admin@gmail.com")

so now I have 2 words in arabic and english the problem is when I query the Arabic word show to me code like this : [u'\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627\u064b']

I want it to return like my inserted word like this : مرحباً

Comment: I think you are not understanding me. The `TypeError` you are getting is due to `all` being a `list`. You cannot use a `list` where a `str` is expected, so of course you're getting that `[u'...']` garbage, because you're blindly converting a `list` to a `str`. So, to fix it, you want to get the first element of the `list`, which is a `str`. If you're getting other errors related to Unicode, that's a separate issue.

Comment: @univerio ok, I edit my code to : f.write(all[0].username) and I'm getting this error now : UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)

Can u edit my code & answer my question please. I'm facing this from 2 days without fix :(

Comment: Again, that's a separate issue, but very briefly, to write a `unicode` object to a file, you want to encode it first, usually utf-8: `f.write(all[0].username.encode("utf-8"))`.

Comment: @univerio Thank u. it's working now ... all[0].username.encode("utf-8") this working 100%